# Qt client not exiting on Linux

Tags: bitcoin-core, linux, litecoin-qt

I am running Ubuntu 12.04. When I close bitcoin-qt (or any of its derivatives, like litecoin-qt or dogecoin-qt), sometimes it does not completely exit. I then have to run `killall -9 bitcoin-qt`, or sometimes when even that doesn't work, `killall -9 bitcoin-shutoff` (apparently the client calls a `bitcoin-shutoff` process to shut itself down). I am wondering if there is a fix for this, to prevent the client from refusing to close in the future.

Comment: When you check your processes - does it appear as zombie? Does it respond to plain "kill" or remains unresponsive unless you go with "kill -9"?

Comment: It does not respond to kill, only kill -9.

Comment: you need to post debug log, so we can understand what's up with client

Answer (score 1):

Have you set a proxy?

From my experience slow shutdown seems to have to do with slow proxies (for example, Tor).
There is an issue for this: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/2954

If it is not the network thread that hangs, but database synchronization, then killing with -9 can be dangerous.

I'd suggest debugging this by running in gdb, Ctrl-Cing when it hangs, and then getting backtraces for every still-running thread.

Comment: No, no proxies.